# How do I access a Active directory enabled website from the internet?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

How do I access a Active directory enabled ASP.net website om IIS7 from the internet and do authentication against the AD?

Answer (score 1):

If you enable Windows Authentication, set deny users="?" in your web.config, and configure the ASP.NET Active Directory Membership Provider, it works.

Here is how to configure it:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998372

If you need to use Forms Authentication, here is how to configure that:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650308.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it, you dont!

You (and your computer) must be members of the active directory domain.
The browser sends your network credential to the webserver to authenticate.
(and i'm not sure if it will send these details over the internet, or if it will only send them in a LAN)